# Parse Javascript: Skip model attribute while saving

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any way to skip the model class attribute while saving the object. The reason why am putting this question is one of my parse model class have a custom attribute which have no importance at parse table ie it fully used at client for resolving some issues

---------Skip the model class property while saving them to parse